# Calculate total number of null values in a dataset in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, bigdata

I have to calculate the total number of null values in my dataset including all rows and all columns and the output must be an integer that would represent the total number of null values in my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - shorter option

```py
df_agg = df.agg(*[F.sum(F.when(F.isnull(c), 1)) for c in df.columns])
null_cnt = sum(df_agg.head().asDict().values())
```

Test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (None, None), (3, 4)], ['col1', 'col2'])

df_agg = df.agg(*[F.sum(F.when(F.isnull(c), 1)) for c in df.columns])
null_cnt = sum(df_agg.head().asDict().values())

print(null_cnt)
# 2
```

---

Original suggestion:

```py
null_cnt = df.select(
    F.aggregate(
        F.array(*[F.sum(F.when(F.isnull(c), 1)) for c in df.columns]),
        F.expr("0L"),
        lambda sum, x: sum + x
    )
).head()[0]
```

Test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (None, None), (3, 4)], ['col1', 'col2'])

null_cnt = df.select(
    F.aggregate(
        F.array(*[F.sum(F.when(F.isnull(c), 1)) for c in df.columns]),
        F.expr("0L"),
        lambda sum, x: sum + x
    )
).head()[0]

print(null_cnt)
# 2
```